# What is the cost of a visa on arrival in Azerbaijan?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, azerbaijan, israeli-citizens

I am a citizen of Israel and am planning to go fo Azerbaijan and it might be a bit tight to obtain an e-visa.

What is the cost of getting a visa on arrival at Heydar Aliyev International Airport, and how long is a procedure (typically)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [official e-visa site](https://evisa.gov.az/en/) you can apply for an 'urgent' e-visa for $50 and it will be ready within 3 hours. (The standard e-visa being $23 and ready within 3 days)

Israeli citizens can also obtain a normal visa on arrival at the airport in Azerbaijan [for $26](https://embassies.gov.il/baku-en/Pages/VISA.aspx).

The time to collect depends on how many flights have come in, and how many passengers are waiting, I've seen several posts commenting on how 'long' it takes and some stating it was 'fairly quick'.